# Redhat linux local user PATH

Tags: path

when i am  login in as local user in redhat linux  and run command echo $ PATH  it is showing me :/sbin: in my path, when i dont have any access to commands like fdisk.
then why it is showing  me :sbin: in PATH

Comment: Have you checked in the sbin folder to see if fdisk is there? Can you show the full output of echoing the PATH?

Comment: [tom@localhost ~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/tom/bin  
[tom@localhost ~]$ fdisk -l
[tom@localhost ~]$
we can see /sbin is in path but i am not getting fdisk -l  output

Comment: If you navigate to the sbin directory can you copy and paste the path from the command line so I can see what it is in your installation? Also, can you run ```ls``` from the command line is the /sbin folder just to make sure fdisk is in there?

Comment: AFAIK - `fdisk` requires root permissions, so you should try with `sudo fdisk -l`, that is why you have sbin in the path - to have access to the commands - not meaning you have the required rights to execute it. And you should explain a bit more what does it mean "I don't have access to commands" - do you get an error message? If yes, please let us know.

Comment: Just checking back to see if the issue is solved now. Did any of the comments help? :)

Comment: hi zain if i use sudo fdisk -l  as local user them it is asking me password for same user  and not root password. then were is sercutity for server if a user can access fdisk /dev/sda and create a partion or  delete partion.

Comment: HI peter David i am sorry for late response. i am not able understand why is /sbin path  is there  in local user account.